# Apache ignite 's exapmle cannot be execute ,the details is below

Tags: apache, h2

When I was running the example from the ignite's website, an error occurred just like this.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2Row has interface org.h2.result.Row as super class" [50000-193]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
```

It cost lots of time to resolve it, but failed.

Comment: Who can help me, I really don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Spring Boot use H2 too, but different version. In my case it was `1.4.193` for Spring and `1.4.191` for Ignite. Between these versions `org.h2.result.Row` was changed from `abstract class` to `interface`

**FIX**

Check, which version of H2 used in your version of Ignite (check there: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/parent/pom.xml, but for your version)

After that add dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.191</version> <!-- Ignite's version -->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resovled,there is no need to config the h2 database bean in default-config.xml . They are conflicting.